# Is it able to rollback Stripe update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I was asked to increase the amount of all plan in Stripe. So I wrote the following script in ruby to delete old plan and create new plan with the same id with different amount:

```
    for stripe_plan in Stripe::Plan.list

      new_amount = (stripe_plan.amount*1.1).floor

      Stripe::Plan.delete(stripe_plan.id)

      new_stripe_plan = Stripe::Plan.create(
        nickname: stripe_plan.nickname,
        amount: new_amount,
        interval: stripe_plan.interval,
        currency: stripe_plan.currency,
        product: stripe_plan.product
      )
```

The problem is if one fails (most likely not), it might result in some plans are updated and others are not, which is not consistent.

The question is: Is there any transaction method to rollback Stripe create, update, delete when it fails?

If this is not a question for stackoverflow, please comment, I will delete this.

Comment: Stripe is an API, so there is most likely not any transaction support. You have to code around it instead. Log all updates so it is easy for you to roll back or repair things if needed.

Comment: @Casper thanks, I'm working with that solution, but I'm still looking for a better way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the price of existing plans, you should [create new plans](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/products-and-plans#changing-and-deleting-plans) with the updated cost, then assign them to the appropriate users. This will allow you to simply check if any users are on old plans if something were to go wrong.

Comment: I see your point. if thing goes wrong, we still have to fix it manually. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. I just realize that my code will affect all plans so doing what you suggest would be better regarding fault tolerance. Take my upvote.